# AngularJS Directive doesn't see $index when used in an id attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2FTEU/3/

In the directive I want to assign a dynamic id tag based upon it's position in an ng-repeat

```
<my-directive id="directive-{{$index}}"></my-directive>
```

What is happening is that when the directive gets rendered, the index is dropped

```
<button id="directive-"></button>
```

How can I use $index in the id for a directive?

**EDIT**
I need to keep the isolate scope. The example posted is just a small example that demonstrated my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{{$parent.$index}}`.

The scope created by ng-repeat contains the `$index` property.  Since `myDirective` creates a new isolate scope, you can use `$parent` to "reach up" to the parent ng-repeat scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your directive `myDirective` is using an isolated scope, which does **not** inherit from the parent scope. Therefore, `$index` isn't accessible anymore.

You can simply create a new scope for your directive, with `{scope : true}`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TpyVY/) is a working version of your Fiddle.

Comment: The reason why it wasn't working is right, but the solution doesn't exactly solve my problem. I need an isolate scope since in my code I pass other parameters in to the directive. The example was a basic directive that allowed me to reproduce the issue. Thanks.